# Vectorized operations on 2 columns of different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function `func` that takes two strings as input and returns an integer as an output. I have two different dataframes and I want to use the 'Name' column of both these dataframes as an input to the function.

Suppose,

```
In [12]: DF1
Out[12]: 
     Name
0   Apple
1  Banana
2  Orange
```

and

```
In [13]: DF2
Out[13]: 
     Name
0  Spider
1     Yak
2    Wolf
```

Now, I want use `func` and provide inputs to it like

```
func('apple','spider')
func('apple','yak')
func('apple','wolf')
func('banana','spider')
...
```

I tried doing this by using `itertools` but as the dataset is large it is taking a lot of time. So how could it be done using vectorized operations or what would be the most efficient way to do it?

edit: I am trying to do something like:

```
for i in DF1['Name']:
    for j in DF2['Name']:
        func(i,j)
```

Comment: Is this what you're doing? `for x, y in itertools.product(df1.Name, df2.name): f(x, y)` Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @COLDSPEED It works, but as I stated the dataset is large, so using itertools is computationally expensive. I know that using vectorized operations in pandas are quite fast reference: [https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6] , but i could not figure out how to implement it in my problem.